# R fGarch: presample matrix for garchSpec()

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to specify GARCH model by function `fGarch::garchSpec()` and i need a specified presample. As defined in manual:

> presample: a numeric three column matrix with start values for the
>              series, for the innovations, and for the conditional
>              variances.

But i am pretty sure, that this is not the correct order. After reading the manuals and codes for functions: 'garchFit', 'garchSpec', 'garchSim' I am still quite confused.

The question is: how to exactly build `presample` matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set an argument to `presample`. It will supply a "good" guess   and in estimating the parameters it will not matter. If you want to simulate data, then I would just make sure the burnin, `n.start`, is large enough.

Let's look at an example:

```
library(fGarch)
## First we simulate some data without setting presample:
# we set up the model by spec:
set.seed(911)
spec <- garchSpec(model = list(mu = 0.02, omega = 0.05, alpha = 0.2, beta = 0.75))
# then simulate our GARCH(1,1) model:
garchSim <- garchSim(spec, n = 200, n.start = 1)
plot(garchSim)
```

[image: Garch(1,1) simulation]

And estimates:

```
    > garchFit(~ garch(1, 1), data = garchSim)
Error Analysis:
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu      -0.02196     0.05800   -0.379   0.7049    
omega    0.03567     0.02681    1.331   0.1833    
alpha1   0.12074     0.04952    2.438   0.0148 *  
beta1    0.84527     0.05597   15.103   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log Likelihood:
 -265.8417    normalized:  -1.329209
```

Let us now try to add a very xtreme presample. In the above model (and this seed) the `presample` was:

```
> spec@presample
Presample: 
  time          z h    y
1    0 -0.4324072 1 0.02
```

now we replace it by `c(100, 0.1, 0.1)`. Since my model is a GARCH(1,1) without any ARMA-part, I only need to set 3 parameters as descriped in the documentation `?garchSpec`. After updating `spec` we estimate the same model:

```
set.seed(911)
spec@presample <- matrix(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), ncol = 3)
garchFit(~ garch(1, 1), data = garchSim)
```

with the same output:

```
Error Analysis:
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu      -0.02196     0.05800   -0.379   0.7049    
omega    0.03567     0.02681    1.331   0.1833    
alpha1   0.12074     0.04952    2.438   0.0148 *  
beta1    0.84527     0.05597   15.103   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log Likelihood:
 -265.8417    normalized:  -1.329209
```

The likelihood and estimates are identical, but notice when we simulate with the new `spec`:

```
set.seed(911)
garchSim <- garchSim(spec, n = 200, n.start = 1)
plot(garchSim)
```

[image: Garch Simulation 2]

, the extreme initial sample supplied messed up our nice simulation. But by increasing the `burn.in` we get:

```
set.seed(911)
garchSim <- garchSim(spec, n = 200, n.start = 100)
plot(garchSim)
```

[image]